# Prove that the product of two evens is even. Generalise to any divisor.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am getting these questions from a book called, *An Inquiry-Based Introduction to Proofs* by Jim Hefferon. However, I do not understand what he means by "Generalise to any divisor.". I thought the divisor would always be 2, given we are talking about an even number.

My solution I have is simply this:
1. $a$ and $b$ are even.
2. $\exists k,m \in \mathbb{Z}: a = 2k$ and $b = 2m$.
3. $a \times b = 2k \times 2m = 2(2km) =$ even.

However, I am not sure if that satisfies the request to "Generalise to any divisor" because I don't really know what that means?
Does anyone know?
Thanks.

Comment: Replace "even" by "multiple of $2$" then you can generalize to any larger integer.

Comment: You made a calculating error, $2k\times 2m=4km$

Comment: $2k \cdot 2m \ne 2(k+m)$ although it *is* even.

Comment: You're right @Daan, thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your answer, you should have $2k\cdot 2m=4mk=2(2mk)$, not $2(k+m)$. Otherwise, your proof is correct.

By generalizing to any divisor, it means that it wants you to prove the following:

> Suppose $n$ and $m$ are both divisible by $k$. Prove that $n\cdot m$ is divisible by $k$.

Comment: Oh yeah that explanation is what I'm looking for. So if I want to go on and do this for n and m as you have stated, do I edit my original post or I answer my post?

Comment: Well, you may accept whichever answer you feel answers your question best, including your own. Editing your own question might make hide the original purpose of it.

Comment: Yes, but I mean generally, sometimes someone will give you a hint, and not the answer, and so you have to continue with your solution. Should you edit and append it to your original post? Or is it preferred that you answer your own post with an updated version?

Comment: If the hint helps you answer your question, you should probably accept that answer. There is no need to then post a full solution to your question.

Comment: ok, thanks @ervx

Answer (score 1):

$2p\times 2k=2^2pk$

$2\mid 2^2pk.$ QED

$np\times nk=n^2pk$

$n\mid n^2pk$.  QED

Comment: Oh yeah, ok so that's what I should be putting if I were to add it. Thanks @RobertFrost

Comment: @Bucephalus yeah, to generalise just means prove for the general case, i.e. for *any* divisor (in this case $n$), not just $2$.